# 'HTTPConnectionPool' object has no attribute 'get_url'

Tags: python, urllib3

this is my codes:

```
import urllib3

url='http://www.google.com/'

http_pool = urllib3.connection_from_url(url)

content = http_pool.get_url('/')

print (content.info())
print ('----------------------------')
page = content.read()

print (page)
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python\test.py", line 24, in <module>
    content = http_pool.get_url('/')
AttributeError: 'HTTPConnectionPool' object has no attribute 'get_url'
```

I goolge it ,but nothing relevant.
It's so strange that i can't figure out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`urllib3 docs`](http://readthedocs.org/docs/urllib3/en/1.2.1/pools.html#urllib3.connectionpool.HTTPConnectionPool.get_url)

```
get_url(url, fields=None, **urlopen_kw)
Deprecated since version 1.0.

Use request() instead.
```